# Macbook Pro taking out broken screen

Tags: macbook-pro, display, firmware

I have a Macbook Pro 16 inch 2019 A2141. The screen is broken and it asks for a firmware password. I am gonna bring my macbook to apple to remove the firmware password but then my screen is still broken and I was thinking to use it as a pc.

**If I disconnect the internal screen, is it gonna display everything on a external monitor if I connect it through HDMI?** Even if I have to restart the system, update it or put in the firmware password. I’m not talking about clamshell mode but literally taking the whole screen out. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We strongly encourage one question per question. Is this basically asking if you can run a portable Mac in [closed clamshell mode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/closed-clamshell) once it’s repaired?

Comment: @bmike I edited my question

Comment: If you take the "whole screen" out, will it fail boot tests?

Comment: I saw recently on internet people who do this to sell MacBook with no screen. There may be some tutorials.